# Additional VSCode autocomplete for Vue along with Volar?

Tags: vue.js, visual-studio-code

I'm getting decent autocomplete with Volar but things like template, slot, and script with export default aren't doing much.

I can type things like 'div' or 'header' hit tab and both the opening and closing tags fully complete but that doesn't work for 'template' or 'slot'.

I didn't see anything in the settings for Volar to add these. Is there another extension I can install that helps?